# Which MSBuild target copies the .dll from a project reference?

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to develop a custom MSBuild task and test it by invoking it from another project in the same solution. Originally I set up `UsingTask` in the test project to reference the .dll in the task project:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="FooTask" AssemblyFile="..\Task\bin\$(Configuration)\Task.dll"/>
<Target Name="RunFooTask" BeforeTargets="Compile">
    <FooTask/>
</Target>
```

This mostly works. But frequently and seemingly at random, building the test project leaves the task project .dll locked by MSBuild and/or Visual Studio, which requires killing the rogue MSBuild process and restarting Visual Studio. This sounds similar to [Visual Studio 2008 locks custom MSBuild Task assemblies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3371545/visual-studio-2008-locks-custom-msbuild-task-assemblies) and [Visual Studio 2008 locks dll in bin folder and doesn't let go of it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1161856/visual-studio-2008-locks-dll-in-bin-folder-and-doesnt-let-go-of-it). But my task is already an `AppDomainIsolatedTask` and I've tried setting `GenerateResourceNeverLockTypeAssemblies`. This does not solve the problem.

So I tried adding a project reference from the test project to the target project, thinking it would copy the .dll into the test project and `UsingTask` could find it there:

```
<UsingTask TaskName="FooTask" AssemblyFile="$(OutputPath)Task.dll" />
```

This *seems* to solve the problem with the .dll being left locked. The problem now is that the .dll has not been copied yet when the task is invoked. If I understand correctly, `BeforeTargets="Compile"` means any time before compile, not necessarily immediately before compile. So I think I need to also specify `AfterTargets` with whatever target copies the .dll from the referenced project. **What target would that be?**

Incidentally, I also tried changing `BeforeTargets="Compile"` to `BeforeTargets="Build"`. Now the .dll is copied before the task runs, but that's because it runs *after* the build! I boiled this down to a test target that doesn't involve `UsingTask` at all:

```
<Target Name="Hello" BeforeTargets="Build">
    <Message Importance="high" Text="Hello" />
</Target>
```

Output:

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: Test, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  Test -> C:\[redacted]\MSBuildTest2\Test\bin\Debug\Test.exe
1>  Hello
```

This makes me doubt everything I thought I knew about what's going on.

Comment: Do you need to run before compile? Usually you'd develop these tasks in a way that doesn't require referencing them from VS because of this reason.

Comment: @MartinUllrich It's a code generator, so yes.

Comment: If you don't want it to lock VS, I suggest splitting the solutions and trying to build a NuGet Package / SDK package containing the task + targets along with integration tests that invoke MSBuild itself, then use the NuGet package in the project you want to use code generation from inside VS.
Nevertheless, I suggest importing the file via a direct path since references are copied AFTER compilation

Comment: @MartinUllrich I packaged the task as a NuGet package and installed it in the project that needs to use it. This has the same effect as a project reference: the .dll does not exist in `$(OutputDir)` until after the build. In other build systems it would be a compile scope dependency, but MSBuild apparently has no concept of that. I also expected `UsingTask` to be able to use `AssemblyName` instead of `AssemblyFile` when consuming a NuGet package, but that doesn't work, either. Perhaps I don't understand the correct usage of `AssemblyName`.

Comment: Maybe a MSBuild task is entirely the wrong thing to use for this purpose. I originally wrote my code generator as a console app, but I thought a build task would be less hacky.

Comment: Both work. but I'd ship an msbuild target inside the NuGet package to reference it. The task wouldn't be packaged as dll to be referenced but into a special directory with the msbuild targets referencing it from there. you can see an example at https://github.com/dasMulli/AssemblyInfoGenerationSdk

Comment: @MartinUllrich Is this what you're talking about: [Bundling .NET build tools in NuGet](https://natemcmaster.com/blog/2017/11/11/build-tools-in-nuget/)? I would accept an answer that says this is an XY problem and I'm doin' it wrong.